# let $(X,d)$ be metric space and y $A$,subsets of $X$

Tags: general-topology

I want to do this topology problem:

let $(X,d)$ be metric space and y $A$ subsets of
$X$ such that $E\cap A \neq
\varnothing$ and $E\cap (X\smallsetminus A) \neq\varnothing$. if $E$ is connected, prove  $E\cap 
\partial A\neq \varnothing$.

I have tried to reason by reduction to the absurd and applying definition but
I don't know if that path is viable.
Could you give me a suggestion? Please

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that question that just consist of a problem statement are unpopular, so please add a description of what you have done to solve the problem yourself. Otherwise you can expect the question to be closed.

Comment: What do you mean by "related"? Probably "connected"?

Comment: Connected is what I want to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean that $E$ is connected. Plus there is no $B$.

The essence is that $E \cap \partial A = \emptyset$, then $(X\setminus A) \cap E$ and $E \cap A$ form a non-trivial partition of $E$. Try to show that.